# Fixed total row of dojo data grid

Tags: dojo, grid, row, fixed

Is there any way to add a fixed (static) row under the data grid header section with v1.7??

So it won't be scrolled with the data item below..

Thanks.

Comment: You mean having a locked header so that nothing in the header scrolls ?

Comment: Yes, I wanna set the first row of the grid and make it work with the original header together. So when I drag the scroll bar, the first row can be fixed like the header section.